# How do I handle a case where the session may not exist?

Tags: jsp, session

I have a JSP page with

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

to prevent Tomcat from automatically creating a session, and a code block similar to

```
1  <%
2  if(request.getSession(false) != null) {
3       session.setAttribute("username", username);
4  }
5  %>
```

Accessing the page gives a "session cannot be resolved to a variable" error that cites line 3.

If the session does not exist, then `request.getSession(false)` should return `null`, and the "if" block should be skipped.  Instead, Tomcat complains that the variable doesn't exist in the block it's supposed to be skipping because the variable doesn't exist.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the JSP specifications say about the `session` attribute of the page directive:

> Indicates that the page requires participation in an (HTTP) session.
>   If true then the implicit script language variable named session of type javax.servlet.http.HttpSession references the current/new session for the page.
>   If false then the page does not participate in a session; the session implicit variable is unavailable, and any reference to it within the body of the JSP page is illegal and shall result in a fatal translation error.
>   Default is true.

So, you use session=false, but expect the session variable to be defined. The spec clearly says that using session=false makes *the session implicit variable [...] unavailable*.

You may still define a variable referring to the session, though:

```
<%
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if (session != null) {
      session.setAttribute("username", username);
  }
%>
```

That said, using scriptlets in a JSP, and modifying the session from a JSP, both show a design problem in your application. A JSP is a view component. This should be done in Java code, inside a controller written in Java. The JSP should only generate HTML, using the JSP EL, the JSTL, and other custom tags if necessary. Learn about MVC.

Comment: <comment deleted by poster>

Comment: No. But you can name the variable the way you want to.